# Span tags applied by javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom

I am working on a text editor in html and js that opens by the context menu.

When the user highlights some text and right clicks a custom menu opens up with the various text format options.

Check this [link](http://jsfiddle.net/hapjbe56/).

This is the main format function:

```
function StyleChange(style,property) {
    var span = document.createElement("span");
    span.style[style] = property;

    if (window.getSelection) {
        var sel = window.getSelection();
        if (sel.rangeCount) {
            var range = sel.getRangeAt(0).cloneRange();
            range.surroundContents(span);
            sel.removeAllRanges();
            sel.addRange(range);
        }
    }
}
```

I am having a couple of problems at the minute with a few little things. is there a way to get it to recognise if there is a span already there as if a user changes the text colour to yellow and the changes his mind it wont let him select any other colour same goes for when trying the use the high light function.

If you making loads of customisations to the text id colour:orange; background:yellow; font-weight:bold; you end up with span within span and it looks messy.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide an example of your issue in a **[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/)**?

Comment: Not related with question problem: you have a mess of pure JavaScript and jQuery. Also all these `onclick="StyleChange('font-style','italic')"` look outdated. I mean it is deprecated way to handle clicks. Also there are multiple same IDs - it's bad.

Comment: Take a look at [updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hapjbe56/2/). Maybe you will take some useful ideas from it.

Comment: If you want to check whether selected text is inside `<span<` (inside already formatted text) or in original `<p>`, you can use ` range.commonAncestorContainer.parentNode.tagName`. [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hapjbe56/3/).

Comment: The code that you change in the jsfiddle worked perfectly for what i need... as for the mix js and jquery... im still learning and didnt think anything of it. where are the multiple of the same ID's

Comment: _im still learning_ - well, that's why I rewrote your code and showed it to you to show how it is supposed to look like. About multiple same IDs: there were 6 `id="displaydiv"` in your original code. I switched them to `class="displaydiv"`.